# как склеить 2 столбца в таблице в 1 mysql

Tags: mysql, table, insert

Имеется Таблица My_TABLE, поля street(LONGTEXT),house(LONGTEXT), пытаюсь в этой ж таблице создать столбец address на основе 2х вышеперечисленных. Но не выходит . Запрос такой,

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (address)
SELECT CONCAT(street, ' ', house) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так

Comment: что именно не выходит? какая ошибка? поле `address` - какой тип?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы ВСТАВЛЯЕТЕ данные. Т.е. в дополнение к существующей записи с имеющимися `street` и `house` и пустым `address` хотите вставить новую запись с пустыми `street` и `house` и заполненным `address`.

Вам же нужно в существующей записи изменить пустое `address` на созданное из имеющихся `street` и `house`. Вставка нового значения в одно из полей существующей записи - это обновление записи, а не вставка. И запрос будет

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
SET address = CONCAT(street, ' ', house);
```

Однако этот подход по сути своей ошибочен (за исключением случая, когда впоследствии поле `address` может подвергнуться корректировке без изменения `street`/`house` или наоборот). Если `address` ВСЕГДА будет соответствовать `street`/`house` - надо вообще исключить поле `address` из структуры таблицы, и получать его значение непосредственно в запросе, в котором оно понадобилось.

**PS.** Если же поле `address` должно появиться в таблице, а сейчас его там нет, то его сначала надо создать. Запросом

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD COLUMN address LONGTEXT;
```

и только потом обновлять его значение показанным выше запросом.

Comment: То что нужно ,я просто импортирую записи из одной б д в другую, поля street/ house не будут больше использоваться в целевой базе. Спасибо!